# Visual studio 2010 Premium MSTest bug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest

The following is the test code.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class MyClass {}
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) { }

        List<MyClass> Test() { return new List<MyClass>(); }
    }
}
```

Then using Visual studio create a union test for method `Test()`.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("ConsoleApplication2.exe")]
    public void TestTest()
    {
        Program_Accessor target = new Program_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        List<MyClass_Accessor> actual;
        actual = target.Test();
        Assert.IsTrue(actual != null);
    }
```

It will get the following exception when running the test. How to workaround the issue?

```
Test method TestProject1.ProgramTest.TestTest threw exception:  
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication2.MyClass]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication2.MyClass_Accessor]'.
```

I tried the following method and it doesn't work too.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> Test1() { return new List<MyClass>(); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program and your method are not public so MSTest and any other code cannot call it. MS Test built wrapper `Program_Accessor` to use your code through reflection.

Change your code to use `public` access modifier and regenerate the test. It is the easiest way to learn unit-testing.

```
public class Program
{
   public class MyClass{}

   static void Main(string[] args) { }

   public List<MyClass> Test() { return new List<MyClass>(); }
}
```

You may use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` if you do not want to make `MyClass` public.

[Friend Assemblies in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)

Comment: I found that both the class `Program` and the method `Test` can be private. The class `MyClass` need to be public. However I prefer `MyClass` not be public.